# How do I select a specific section in a html page when web scraping using bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I am scraping a weather website there are 2 "sections". When i do `Humd = soup.select_one('section:-soup-contains("%")').section.text` it checks the first section but the information i want is in the second section. How do I make it select the second section instead of searching and selecting the first?

42%

**How would i get the 42%?** I have tried if soup contains '%' go to div, then the span and the text but it returns morning. Code below.

`Humd = soup.select_one('section:-soup-contains("%")').div.span.text`

The website: https://weather.com/en-GB/weather/today/l/12ad1b2264138ebcb368cc8f5b7435cb276f7cdea8de4cf37f5bd9c22070aa76

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP0Zb.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VocDS.png

I have also tried `Humd = soup.select_one('section2:-soup-contains("%")').div.span.text`
but its returns 'has no attribute div'.

My code https://replit.com/@HarshitJagarlam/DangerousSpitefulCopyright#main.py

Comment: what is the url, and what have you tried until now?

Comment: I have tried `Humd = soup.select_one('section:-soup-contains("%")').section2` but it gives none when I print it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select by id or class:

```
section = soup.find('section', { 'id': 'section2-id' })

section = soup.find('section', { 'class': 'section2-class' })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
soup.find('span', {'data-testid': 'PercentageValue'}).text
```

i have this value here
[image]

---

btw this site blocked in my country and i need to change my ip with python for testing this row, but i didn't do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Select your elements more specific and use also the parent that contains *Humidity*:

```
soup.select_one('.TodayDetailsCard--detailsContainer--16Hg0 div:-soup-contains("Humidity")').span.text
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://weather.com/en-GB/weather/today/l/12ad1b2264138ebcb368cc8f5b7435cb276f7cdea8de4cf37f5bd9c22070aa76'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text)

soup.select_one('.TodayDetailsCard--detailsContainer--16Hg0 div:-soup-contains("Humidity")').span.text
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will reliably retrieve the value next to 'Humidity':

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://weather.com/en-GB/weather/today/l/12ad1b2264138ebcb368cc8f5b7435cb276f7cdea8de4cf37f5bd9c22070aa76"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

hum = soup.find('div', string='Humidity').next_sibling
print(hum.text)
```

Result:

```
54%
```

Documentation for beautifulSoup can be found at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#